# Can Mathematics Educators be used to ask about terminology questions?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask a question about the best term to use describe problems such as these where there are multiple steps to the problem.

[image]

Because I am looking for a term, I am considering it a terminology question.

I asked on MathOverflow, but they said it wasn't professional enough to ask over there and that I should ask on Mathematics Educators instead. Is Mathematics Educators the right place? I've browsed through the questions on the site, and I am not sure if it is a fit. Thanks for any advice or guidance.

Comment: Anyway, it might be called "_long subtraction_".

Comment: [Here's a link for SE.Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/).  Most typical math questions would tend to go there, rather than on MathOverflow.  By contrast, MathOverflow's more for stuff about research-level mathematics.

Comment: A corresponding question on [math.meta.se]: [Can I ask a question about terminology here?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35122)

Comment: It seems to me to be a reasonable question to ask here.

Comment: I find that MSE has really eschewed general math questions (about math) and only wants homework questions and puzzle questions.  FWIW MO actually is more inclusive than MSE (that said, it's too easy for MO.)  MESE sometimes seems to accept questions that a legalist might exclude (especially if MSE doesn't allow them, even though it should.)  Plus the people are just nicer here.  Or at MO.  Than MSE.  /not entirely trolling